# Factoring some qubits with Kronecker product

Tags: quantum-state, textbook-and-exercises

I have this quantum state:
$$|\phi \rangle =\frac{1}{4\sqrt{2}}|000\rangle +\frac{3-\sqrt{5}i}{8}|001\rangle +\frac{1}{4\sqrt{2}}|010\rangle +\frac{3-\sqrt{5}i}{8}|011\rangle \\+\frac{1}{4\sqrt{2}}|100\rangle +\frac{3-\sqrt{5}i}{8}|101\rangle +\frac{1}{4\sqrt{2}}|110\rangle +\frac{3-\sqrt{5}i}{8}|111\rangle $$
And I have to use Kronecker product to factorize that state into individual qubits (Image below). I'm not sure where to start, any hint would be appreciated

$$|\phi \rangle =\left| Q_2 \right. \rangle \left| Q_1 \right. \rangle \left| Q_0 \right. \rangle =\left| Q_2Q_1Q_0 \right. \rangle $$

Comment: Partial trace your $|\phi\rangle$ for each qubit, if it can be written in the product state, then it's the answer.

Comment: Hopefully @narip can expand his suggestion a bit more, but consider playing around with products of $|+>$ with itself to see what it looks like.

Comment: With OP's notation, *if* $|\phi\rangle$ can be written as direct product form, we then can calculate it with $$Tr_{10}\left( |\phi \rangle \langle \phi | \right) =\left| Q_2 \right. \rangle \langle Q_2|
\\
Tr_{20}\left( |\phi \rangle \langle \phi | \right) =|Q_1\rangle \langle Q_1|
\\
Tr_{21}\left( |\phi \rangle \langle \phi | \right) =|Q_0\rangle \langle Q_0|.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a=\frac{1}{4 \sqrt{2}}$ and $b = \frac{3-\sqrt{5}i}{8}$.
Then we can factor out $|0\rangle$ from the first 4 terms, and we can factor out $|1\rangle$ from the last 4 terms. This gives

\begin{align*}
|0\rangle \left(a|00\rangle + b|01\rangle + a|10\rangle + b|11\rangle \right ) + \\
|1\rangle \left(a|00\rangle + b|01\rangle + a|10\rangle + b|11\rangle \right).
\end{align*}
Now, factor out the common factor and you get
$$
\left(|0\rangle + |1\rangle \right) \left(a|00\rangle + b|01\rangle + a|10\rangle + b|11\rangle \right).
$$
Repeat the same procedure on the right-most factor.
Hint: the first two qubits will be in the state $|+\rangle |+\rangle$.